# Mathematica does not help in this integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I am trying to solve this integral with assumptions:

```
Assuming[Element[j, Integers] && j >= 0, Integrate[ ρ^(j + 1)*
Cos[θ]^j Sum[Binomial[j, k] (- 1)^(j - k) (2 ρ^2)^k, {k, 0, j}],
{ρ, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}]]
```

I know this integral is different from zero at even values of `j`. In fact this is expected:

```
FullSimplify[Assuming[Element[j, Integers] && j >= 0,
Integrate[Cos[θ]^j,{θ, 0, 2 π}]],
Assumptions -> Mod[j, 2] == 0]
```

However, the following returns zero for even and odd values of `j`, and it is puzzling me:

```
Assuming[Element[j, Integers] && j > 0 && Mod[j, 2] == 0, 
Integrate[ ρ^(j + 1) Sum[Binomial[j, k] (- 1)^(j - k) (2 ρ^2)^k,
{k, 0, j}], {ρ, 0, 1}]]
```

I do not know what I am ignoring or doing wrong.

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: I get this: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2sgd5.png) mathematica 10.0.2

Comment: So, zero for even an odd values for 'j'. However, it cannot be as providing values for j from zero to, namely, 10, the integral gives a nonzero value for even 'j'.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas You are not doing anything wrong. It is just a bug in Integrate.

Comment: (1) This may be more  to your liking. `Integrate[\[Rho]^(j + 1) Sum[
   Binomial[j, k] (-1)^(j - k) (2 \[Rho]^2)^k, {k, 0, j}, 
   Assumptions -> Element[j, Integers] && j > 0], {\[Rho], 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[j, Reals] && j > 0]`

Comment: (2) In contrast to the comment by @RolfMertig, it is not a bug in `Integrate` that it gave what it gave. Providing assumptions of integrality is always dangerous there because `Integrate` relies on `Simplify` and that latter, with integrality assumptions, might miss isolated cases. This issue has had ample discussion in MSE.

Comment: (3) I have this solution: `(2^(-2 - j/2) \[Pi] ((-1)^(1 + j) Csc[(j \[Pi])/2] Gamma[1 + j] +  Csc[(3 j \[Pi])/2] (-((Beta[1/2, -1 - (3 j)/2, 1 + j] Gamma[-(j/2)])/Gamma[-1 - (3 j)/2]) + Gamma[1 + j])))/(
Gamma[-(j/2)] Gamma[2 + (3 j)/2])` which returns indeterminate for even and odd values for `j`. However, if you try `Table[Integrate[\[Rho]^(j + 1) Sum[Binomial[j, k] (-1)^(j - k) (2 \[Rho]^2)^k, {k, 0, j}, 
    Assumptions -> Element[j, Integers] && j > 0], {\[Rho], 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[j, Reals] && j >= 0], {j, 0, 10, 2}]`, you got useful result. That is why I cannot understand.

Comment: +1 because it led me to an interesting study, cf. my answer

Comment: I finally got a useful result, see my comment to Dr. Wolfgang Hintze

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Daniel pointed correctly out that problems related to Integrate have been the subject of many discussion here, 
I found it worthwhile to study this case in detail, because a condition including Mod was not discussed up to now, as far as I know. The aim is to find out if there is a bug, and if so, where exactly it is sitting, and/or, if possible, to provide rules to avoid the problems.

The difficulty can be traced back in its simplest form to the integral (the integrand is just the sum over binomials) :

$$\int_0^1 \left(2 x^2-1\right)^j \, dx$$

and the problem appears with an assumption of the type `Mod[j,2] == 0`.

*1) Rephrasing the problem with some example cases*

For the time being let me just show some of the most elementary cases I have found which show the same "naughty" behaviour.

The "classical" case first:

```
f1 = Integrate[( -1 + 2  x^2)^j, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {j > -1, Mod[j, 2] == 0}]

(*
Out[10]= 0
*)
```

Now replace the factor 2 by a symbol "a"

```
f2 = Integrate[( -1 + a  x^2)^j, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {j > -1, Mod[j, 2] == 0}]

(*
Out[11]= 0
*)
```

The other way round, let the factor be 1, and add the term "a"

```
f3 = Integrate[( a +   x^2)^j, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {j > -1, Mod[j, 2] == 0}]

(*
Out[12]= 0
*)
```

Or let the power be a quantity "b"

```
f4 = Integrate[( a +   x^b)^j, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {j > -1, Mod[j, 2] == 0}]

(*
Out[13]= ConditionalExpression[0, Re[b] > 0]
*)

Simplify[%, b > 0]

(*
Out[14]= 0
*)
```

Letting `a -> 1` returns the integral unevaluated

```
f5 = Integrate[( 1 +   x^b)^j, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {j > -1, Mod[j, 2] == 0}]

(*
Out[16]= Integrate[(1 + x^b)^j, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {j > -1, Mod[j, 2] == 0}]
*)
```

The same results are obtained for any explicit integer number exept zero in place of the 2 in `Mod[j,2] == 0`.

Now take anything except an explicit non zero integer

```
f6 = 
 Integrate[(a +   x^2)^j, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {j > -1, Mod[j, 1/2] == 0}]

(*
Out[23]= ConditionalExpression[
 a^j Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, -j, 3/2, -(1/a)], Re[a] > 0]
*)
```

Which is different from zero.

The same non zero result appears if we take `Sqrt[2], Pi` or an undefined symbol `k` as the module.

*2) Different classes of exact solutions of the integral*

First we caculate some exact values of the intergral at explicitly non-negative integer points

```
t1 = Table[Integrate[(-1 + 2 x^2)^j, {x, 0, 1}], {j, 0, 10}]

(*
Out[38]= {1, -(1/3), 7/15, -(9/35), 107/315, -(151/693), 835/3003, -(1241/
  6435), 26291/109395, -(40427/230945), 69299/323323}
*)
```

and `ListPlot` them

```
pt1 = ListPlot[t1, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "The integral t1 = \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \
\(1\)]\)(2 \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \
\(2\)]\)-1\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(j\)]\)\[DifferentialD]x\nat \
integer points j", PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], 
  PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1.1}, AxesLabel -> {"j", "t1"}]
(* 150412_Plot _pt1.jpg *)
```

[image]

Then we calculate the integral without the Mod-condition but with the natural assmption `j > -1`, appending a neutral `Simplify`:

```
g1 = Integrate[(-1 + 2 x^2)^j, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> j > -1] // Simplify

(*
Out[40]= (-Sqrt[\[Pi]] Beta[1/2, -(1/2) - j, 
   1 + j] + (1 - (-1)^j Cos[j \[Pi]]) Gamma[-(1/2) - j] Gamma[1 + j])/(2 Sqrt[
 2 \[Pi]])
*)
```

The plot of this complex function versus j looks like

```
pg1 = Plot[{Re[g1], Im[g1]}, {j, 0, 4}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Plot g1\nblue curve = Re\nred cureve = Im"]
(* 150410_Plot _pg1.jpg *)
```

[image]

At the integer points it concides with tg1:

```
tg1 = Table[g1, {j, 1, 10}] // FullSimplify

(*
Out[54]= {-(1/3), 7/15, -(9/35), 107/315, -(151/693), 835/3003, -(1241/
  6435), 26291/109395, -(40427/230945), 69299/323323}
*)
```

Now we apply the Mod condition alone

```
g2c = Integrate[(-1 + 2 x^2)^j, {x, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> Mod[j, 2] == 0]

(*
Out[52]= ConditionalExpression[-(Beta[1/2, -(1/2) - j, 1 + j]/(2 Sqrt[2])), j > -1]
*)
```

and execute  `Simplify` afterwards (if done jointly, the notorious 0 reaults).

```
g2 = Simplify[g2c, j > -1]

(*
Out[53]= -(Beta[1/2, -(1/2) - j, 1 + j]/(2 Sqrt[2]))
*)
```

The plots gives us a surprise

```
Plot[g2, {j, 0, 4}, PlotLabel -> "Plot g2 (real function) versus"]
(* 150410_Plot _pg2.jpg *)
```

[image]

Applying the Mod condition directly to the integand gives us still another function:

```
g3 = 
 Integrate[Simplify[(-1 + 2 x^2)^j, Mod[j, 2] == 0], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {j > -1}]

(*
Out[72]= ((-1)^j Gamma[-(1/2) - j] Gamma[1 + j])/(2 Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]) + (
 Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Gamma[1 + j])/(
 2 Gamma[3/2 + j]) + ((-2)^
  j Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2) - j, -j, 1/2 - j, 1/2])/(1 + 2 j)
*)

pg3 = Plot[{Re[g3], Im[g3]}, {j, 0, 4}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Plot g3\nblue curve = Re\nred cureve = Im"]
(* 150410_Plot _pg3.jpg *)
```

[image]

In this case the values at the integer point do not conincide with t1

```
t3 = Table[g3, {j, 1, 10}]

(* Out[73]= {1/3, 7/15, 9/35, 107/315, 151/693, 835/3003, 1241/6435, 26291/109395, 40427/230945, 69299/323323}
*)
```

But g3 gives the absolute values.

*3) Discussion*

In view of the multitude of strange results obtained here it is not easy to draw valid general conclusions.

I would state, however, first of all that we have a buggy behaviour here because Mathematica returns false results instead of refusing the caculation at all or at least give warnings.

Sufficient ingredients to produce the observed buggy behaviour are:

(i) two branch points (like at `x=-1` and `x=+1` in the current case) and an integration path on the branch cut and going beyond one of the branch points

(ii) the combined conditions `j>-1` and `Mod[j,2]==0`

The two conditions in question are complementary in the sense that they lead - when continued to the real j-axis - to different classes of functions as follows

a) `j>-1` (bounded oscillatory, g1)

b) `Mod[j,2,]==0`, or any non-zero integer instead of 2 (poles, g2)

If we request both conditions to hold together the result is zero. 
This Looks as if Mathematica cannot decide which class is to be chosen, and therefore gives zero.

I would appreciate a discussion with other users interested in this topic.

Comment: Very nice explanation. It is very interesting that Mathematica finds the correct result with a variable change `x=2\[Rho]^2-1`. Thus, `Integrate[ ((x + 1)/2)^(j/2) x^j/4, {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> Element[j, Integers] && j >= 0]` gives `2^(-2 - j/2) Gamma[1 + j] (((-1)^j Gamma[1 + j/2])/Gamma[2 + (3 j)/2] + Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[-(j/2), 1 + j, 2 + j, -1])`, which solves my problem.